# Looping to find letters in a column on VBA

Tags: vba, excel

My macro is to send emails for some clients. It sends the email only if there is a X at one of the lines of the column B, so then it sends the whole line to the client by creating a new sheet that goes attached to the client on the email.
The problem is that I need to create a loop to count all the columns that contain the letter X, because this macro is counting only the first line that contains the letter X and then the other ones don't go to the new sheet and consequently it doesn't go to the client. Everything is OK in my macro, despite of the counter. When i run it, just the first line that contains the X goes to the client, and the others don't. Can you guys help me?

**Code:**

```
LinhaInicio = 1
While Workbooks(planilha).Sheets("Boletas").Cells(LinhaInicio, 2) <> "X"
    LinhaInicio = LinhaInicio + 1
Wend
LinhaFim = LinhaInicio
While Workbooks(planilha).Sheets("Boletas").Cells(LinhaFim, 2) = "X"
    LinhaFim = LinhaFim + 1
Wend
LinhaFim = LinhaFim - 1
RangeInicio = Workbooks(planilha).Sheets("Boletas").Cells(LinhaInicio, 26).Address
RangeFim = Workbooks(planilha).Sheets("Boletas").Cells(LinhaFim, 34).Address
Set RangeCopiar = ActiveSheet.Range(RangeInicio, RangeFim)
```

Comment: what's the code look like?

Comment: LinhaInicio = 1
While Workbooks(planilha).Sheets("Boletas").Cells(LinhaInicio, 2) <> "X"
    LinhaInicio = LinhaInicio + 1
Wend

LinhaFim = LinhaInicio
While Workbooks(planilha).Sheets("Boletas").Cells(LinhaFim, 2) = "X"
    LinhaFim = LinhaFim + 1
Wend

LinhaFim = LinhaFim - 1

RangeInicio = Workbooks(planilha).Sheets("Boletas").Cells(LinhaInicio, 26).Address

RangeFim = Workbooks(planilha).Sheets("Boletas").Cells(LinhaFim, 34).Address

Set RangeCopiar = ActiveSheet.Range(RangeInicio, RangeFim)

Thats the part that needs the loop to find the others X

Comment: Add the code to your question, and format it using the `{}` button. Code in comments is not readable

Comment: Yep, for me, it would be much more difficult to troubleshoot otherwise.

Comment: i will add the whole macro to my question, does it help?

Comment: yeah, I can see your issue though.  your main loop should include the entire scope of the procedure that emails out the sheet.  so that way you're continuing to look for x's

Comment: Do you know how to correct it Clyde?

Comment: And how can i add the code to my question? I tried to use the {} but it didnt work

Comment: Click `edit` right under the tags in your question

Comment: but how can i add the code, it says i cant

Answer (score 0):

Maybe Try something like this:

```
Dim vArr As Variant
Dim LinhaFim As Long
Sub mainLoop()
    'put all values into variant array vArr
    vArr = Workbooks(planilha).Sheets("Boletas").UsedRange
    For i = LBound(vArr) To UBound(vArr)

        If vArr(i, 2) = "X" Then
            Nestedloops (i) 'initiate nested loops
            i = LinhaFim    'artificially increment counter
        End If

    Next i
End Sub


Sub Nestedloops(LinhaIncio As Long)
    With Workbooks(planilha).Sheets("Boletas")
        LinhaFim = linhaInicio
        While vArr(LinhaFim, 2) = "X"
            LinhaFim = LinhaFim + 1
        Wend
        LinhaFim = LinhaFim - 1
        RangeInicio = .Cells(LinhaInicio, 26).Address
        RangeFim = .Cells(LinhaFim, 34).Address
        Set RangeCopiar = ActiveSheet.Range(RangeInicio, RangeFim)

        'email code goes here

    End With
End Sub
```

Tim could come up with something better though might want to see what he comes up with

Comment: Clyde, still not working as you said. I tried to search for everything on the internet. Lets wait for Tim then.

Comment: in the event he doesn't - that second one I'm gonna tweak minimally after I get off the phone with this customer

Comment: sorry rough day today - not sure if this helps or not but the issue is your first loop is looking for the first x the second loop looking for the end of the x's and then your not climbing back up to look for more x's so it needs to be contained in its own loop.  but the counter should increment beyond the number of x's otherwise it'll duplicate the email information.  not sure exactly what the data looks like but this might get you a little closer at least

Comment: I got it. Do you know how to fix it? I mean, to make my loop climb back and get the others X?

Comment: yeah you could do something like count the number of rows in your dataset and while i < datasetlength 'do all code stuff wend

Comment: Clyde, can you do like you did before? Send me the macro, because i tried here and it didnt work.

Comment: just now had to make an edit -         LinhaFim = linhaInicio 
        While vArr(LinhaFim, 2) = "X"

Comment: I cant believe whats going on with my macro :(
Still not working

Comment: unmark the question as answered you might get better visibility on it

Comment: How can I send you the whole macro? so then you can see it and check wheres the problem

Comment: k got it gonna take a look through it

Answer (score 0):

you wanna search the X letter to columns or rows, sorry I didn't understand what you try to say. You want to create a loop to count all the X letter for every row and column or only for every row from a column?

Comment: lonut, my macro search for the lines at the column B that contain the letter X, so then it sends an email for the clients by creating a new sheet with the lines that have the X at the column B, but it works only if the X are in sequence. So when there is the letter X at the line 3 and line 5, just the line 3 goes to the sheet. Got it?

Comment: i don't know if you have defined an array but if you have your code should look like this:
for i=2 to ubound (your_array,1) 
  If your_array(i,2)= X then 
 your condition 
end if 
next I
if you don't have an array you should define one, it will improve your code.

Answer (score 0):

here is how you define an array:

```
Dim timelinessSheet, o As Variant
timelinessSheet = Worksheets("your_sheet_name").Range("A2:X" & Worksheets("your_sheet_name").Cells(Worksheets("your_sheet_name").Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row).Value
```

and then your code

```
dim i as long
for i=2 to ubound (timelinessSheet,1)
 if  timelinessSheet(i,2)= X then 
   Your_condition 
 end if 
next I
```